# How can I simulate an Alt+Tab using Win32 hooks?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I've written this C++ program using VS2010 to detect when the user is making a double middle mouse button click, switch to the next window (as Alt+Tab does) and stop the hook chain. Here's my code:

DLL:

```
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode<0)
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL,nCode,wParam,lParam);

    if (wParam == WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK) 
    {
        PostMessage(GetActiveWindow(),WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_NEXTWINDOW,0);
    }
    else 
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL,nCode,wParam,lParam);
    // if EVERYTHING_IS_OK
    return TRUE;
}
```

EXE:

```
do{
nMenu = choose();
switch (nMenu)
{
case 1:
    hLib = LoadLibrary(cLibName);
    hProc = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(hLib, "HookProc");
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, hProc, hLib, NULL);
    break;
case 2:
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    break;
case 0:
    ;
}
} while (nMenu);
```

I launch the program and set the hook, then the program hangs and mouse stops working in most apps (keeps working in Chrome though). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell.  Do favor WM_MOUSE_LL, much easier to get going since it doesn't require injecting a DLL.  You do have to pump a message loop, can't use a console mode app.

Comment: If what you are describing is the goal, I would just use AutoHotKey. It already handles all the hooks for you, and allows to send Alt-Tab to the system.

Comment: @7vies actually I'm just trying to understand how hooks work, and I already use AutoHotkey :)

Comment: @Hans so you're saying that using high-level mouse hook with a console mode app isn't possible?

Comment: No, I never said anything like that.  Only a low-level mouse hook requires a message loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks are evil if they are not used as notifications only. The MSDN highly recommends calling `CallNextHookEx()` for a reason. You **cannot** know at which point in the calling chain you are. This makes your code fragile even though it might appear to work at first.

You depend on other users of the hook API to be nice to you, i.e. to call you. If someone (like you) does not do it, your code breaks.

Without going into further detail where your code breaks, I think that it is not very surprising that

> the mouse stops working in most apps

if you shut up the other users of the mouse hook by returning `TRUE`, is it?